# Correspondência de conteúdo do comboBox

Tags: javafx

Como fazer com que as opções do `comboBox`, correspondam com índices numéricos? Exemplo, no meu banco eu salvo apenas números de 1 a 8. E na aplicação eu mostro pro meu usuário nomes, eu quero que esses nomes correspondam com esse números. Estava tentando usar `substrings` para fazer isso.

1 -> A

2 -> B

3 -> C

4 -> D

5 -> E

6 -> F

7 -> G

8 -> H

preencho combo com os "nomes"

```
 meuCombo.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H");


pojo.setDoPojo(meuCombo.getTypeSelector().substring(1 , 2))
```

Observação: Eu postei apenas esse trecho de código apenas para ilustrar, quero apenas um direcionamento do que fazer, não estou pedindo nada pronto.

Comment: Como assim?, Você quer pegar os itens pela posição? por exemplo o item B na posição 2 e assim por diante?

Comment: Isso, eu vou mostrar A, porém não vou "salvar" A, vou salvar 1.

Comment: essa setDoPojo é onde você salva?

Comment: Cada dado inserido no combo box recebe uma posição assim como no array, por exemplo se você usar a combobox.getItemAt( 0 ); retornaria o A se coloca 1 retornaria o B e assim por diante, Não poderia ser assim? ou necessariamente tem que o A começar por 1?

Comment: @AndersonHenrique desde já agradeço sua atenção, então teria que começar pelo 1. setDoPojo é dos getters e setters do pojo.

Comment: Já que o banco de dados armazena somente a faixa 1-8 porque não fazer índice + 1?? Assim, ao selecionar o item "B" ficaria meuCombo.getSelectionModel.getSelectedIndex() + 1 = 2, e 2 seria armazenado no BD. Também não entendi porque armazenar apenas 8 valores em 1 banco de dados, um array seria suficiente.

Comment: me de um exemplo então, de como eu devo fazer, fazendo favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que sua tabela no banco de dados é algo do tipo:

```
+-------+-------+
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   A   |
+-------+-------+
|   2   |   B   |
+-------+-------+
|  ...  |  ...  |
+-------+-------+
```

Supondo ainda que você recebe os dados com um select parecido com isto: `select col2 from tabela order by col1` (Para que fiquem ordenados pelo índice e, portanto, tenham posições determinadas). Abstraindo o tratamento que você dá a esses dados na sua aplicação, vou pular para a parte do comboBox. Digamos que o usuário clicou no item C, o código para pegar o índice correto seria o seguinte:

```
// ... código anterior

// Se o usuário clicou em C (Terceira posição) index terá o valor 2 + 1 = 3
int index = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() + 1;

// Caso queira imprimir na tela o item selecionado: (nome terá o valor "C")
String nome = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

Como não sei os detalhes do que você quer fazer acredito que o exposto acima é suficiente para sanar seu problema.